# How to fix the problem with decimal numbers in a factorial function?

Tags: r, decimal, factorial

I am writing a code for the factorial function. My code is as follows:

```
f <- function(n) {
  factorial <- 1
  if( n < 0 )
    print("Factorial of negative numbers is not possible")
  else if( n == 0 )
    print("Factorial of 0 is 1")
  else {
    for(i in 1:n)
      factorial <- factorial * i
    print(paste("Factorial of ",n," is ",factorial))
  }
}
```

My problem with this code is for decimal numbers as input. For example for `f(6.5)` my code computes 720, but we know 6.5 ! does not exist. For decimal numbers like `6.5, 5/2`, or `sqrt(2)` I would like to see a message like

```
"The factorial for this number does not exist".
```

How can I fix this problem in my code?

Comment: Please [format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) your code, this time I've helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? This stops if `n` and `as.integer(n)` is not identical.

```
f <- function(n) {
  if (as.integer(n) != n) {
    stop("The factorial for this number does not exist")
  }
  factorial <- 1
  if( n < 0 )
    print("Factorial of negative numbers is not possible")
  else if( n == 0 )
    print("Factorial of 0 is 1")
  else {
    for(i in 1:n)
      factorial <- factorial * i
    print(paste("Factorial of ",n," is ",factorial))
  }
}


f(5)
# [1] "Factorial of  5  is  120"
f(6.5)
# Error in f(6.5) : The factorial for this number does not exist
f(5/2)
# Error in f(5/2) : The factorial for this number does not exist
f(sqrt(2))
# Error in f(sqrt(2)) : The factorial for this number does not exist
```